# Why does my ema 15 and ema 200 look the same?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm not sure if I coded something wrong or just don't seem to understand what an `exponential moving average` does.

I'm calculating a moving average on SPY 5 minute tick data at ema 15 and ema 200.

They are exactly the same once the 200 starts.  This is the code I used.

```
def EMA(df, column, window, alpha = .2):
    """
    

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : dataframe.
    column : column to compute the EMA
    window : the window of the EMA

    Returns
    -------
    df with ema column.

    """
    
    df = df.copy()
    
    values = np.array(df[column])
    window2 = 'ema_'+str(window)
    df[window2] = df[column].ewm(min_periods = window, alpha=0.3, adjust=False).mean()
    
    return df

df = avg.EMA(df = df, column = 'adjusted_close', window = 15)
df = avg.EMA(df = df, column = 'adjusted_close', window = 200)
```

Is there something glaringly obvious or is it doing what it's supposed to and I don't understand the ema like I thought I did?

Comment: To debug filtering problems, try inputting a sequence with a known result. E.g. all 1's, or all 0's, or all 0's except for one 1.

Comment: yep. Found a calculator online and compared results.  Figured out that I shouldn't be using `alpha` but '`span` as the smoothing parameter.  Thanks.